# How to pull data table from a link which is in an excel cell?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have an Excel file where I would like to pull monthly data basis from a website. So there will be a total of 12 links for the whole year. The links are in a sheet named LINK; suppose, the range is A1 to A20. I can pull that data using a power query. But in that way, links will not be changeable, and for each month a single power query to be developed. And it may increase the loadability of the file.

Is there any way of referencing the link by cell no i.e. A1, A2, A3, etc, and using power query or VBA it will pull the data table?

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so please toggle checkmark next to that answer to mark issue solved

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like perhaps you want to get the data from a bunch of URLs that you specify in a column in excel

[image]

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962

https://www.wisdomaxis.com/technology/software/data/for-reports/Data%20Blending%20File%20One.xlsx

https://www.wisdomaxis.com/technology/software/data/for-reports/Data%20Refresh%20Sample%20Data.xlsx

https://www.wisdomaxis.com/technology/software/data/for-reports/Data%20Join%20vs%20Data%20Blending.xlsx

Powerquery that reads in all those links, and combines them. Links can change as needed, with more/less added within the source range

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents([Column1]), null, true)),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "data", each Table.PromoteHeaders([Custom]{[Item=[Custom][Item]{0},Kind="Sheet"]}[Data])),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom1",{{"Column1", "Link"}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Custom"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns" [data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "data", List,List)
in #"Expanded Data"
```